# Querying over DOM inside the handler of an event

Tags: javascript, events, animation, dojo

I'm using DOJO to create some animations. I'm trying to animate an `h1` inside a section when the mouse is hovering the section.

**This does work:**

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.0/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, isDebug: true"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="section">
            <div id="title">Something</div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```js
require(["dojo/fx", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/mouse","dojo/query","dojo/domReady!"], function(fx, on, dom, mouse,query) {
    var section = dom.byId("section"),
        title = dom.byId("title");

    on(section, mouse.enter, function(evt){
        fx.slideTo({
            node: title, 
            top: "0"
        }).play();
    });

    on(section, mouse.leave, function(evt){
        fx.slideTo({
            node: title, 
            top: "200"
        }).play();
    });
});
```

**What I'd like to get working (It doesn't):**

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.0/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, isDebug: true"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <h1>Something</h1>
        </section>
    </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```js
require(["dojo/fx", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/mouse","dojo/query","dojo/domReady!"], function(fx, on, dom, mouse,query) {
    var section = query("section");

    on(section, mouse.enter, function(evt){
        fx.slideTo({
            node: query("h1",this), 
            top: "0"
        }).play();
    });

    on(section, mouse.leave, function(evt){
        fx.slideTo({
            node: query("h1",this), 
            top: "200"
        }).play();
    });
});
```

I'm trying to get the `h1` element, using `query("h1",this)`, to slide it. All I get is an error in my development tools. I have tried searching for a solution, but I'm unable to find one. How can I resolve this issue?

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLHeadingElement] has no method 'getBoundingClientRect'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `query` doesn't return a node, it returns a `NodeList`.  You can see this in the error, which refers to `Object [object HTMLHeadingElement]` — this is really an Array-like object (`Object [...]`) containing a single item, an `HTMLHeadingElement`.

You need the DomNode, so the easiest solution is to change this:

```
node: query("h1", this)
```

to this:

```
node: query("h1", this)[0]
```

Note this will only work as long as the query returns a valid node.  Otherwise, you'll get an out of bounds error.

[You can see more in the API documentation for dojo/query.](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojo/query)